# Maintain Scroll Bar position of a div within a gridview after a PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, scroll

I used the following piece of code in the web.config in order to maintain the scrollbar position after a server postback:

```
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" >
</pages>
```

All is working fine, but now i have a gridview encapsuled within a div with a scrollbar in the div (internal scrollbar).

When an event occur on one of the rows inside the gridview, the internal scrollbar doesn't maintain its original position unlike the outer one.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is by design: that setting is only applicable to the same position in the client browser. I do not believe it takes affect for any scrollbars added within a `<DIV>` element like within your Gridview.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For future reference:

The normal procedure is to write the following in the web.config file:

```
  <system.web>
    <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" >
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

This will preserve the scroll bar position of all web pages.

If you have a scroll bar within a gridview (or div) then use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var strCook = document.cookie;
        if (strCook.indexOf("!~") != 0) {
            var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
            var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
            var strPos = strCook.substring(intS + 2, intE);
            document.getElementById("grdWithScroll").scrollTop = strPos;
        }
    }
    function SetDivPosition() {
        var intY = document.getElementById("grdWithScroll").scrollTop;
        document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
    }
</script>
```

And the div must be as follows:

```
<div id="grdWithScroll" …………  onscroll="SetDivPosition()">
```

http://michaelsync.net/2006/06/30/maintain-scroll-position-of-div-using-javascript-aspnet-20

Comment: onscroll can sometimes have performance issues since it runs many times as the user is scrolling. Depending on the navigation methods, you might be able to call SetDivPosition() on certain click events so that the cookie is set just once before leaving the page. I used your implementation on a page when any link within a div was clicked, and attached it like this:         $(function () {
            $('#myDivID a').click(function () {
                SetDivPosition();
            });
        });

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
               var h = document.getElementById("<%=hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>");
               document.getElementById("<%=scrollArea.ClientID%>").scrollTop = h.value;
              }
   function SetDivPosition() {
           var intY = document.getElementById("<%=scrollArea.ClientID%>").scrollTop;
           var h = document.getElementById("<%=hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>");
           h.value = intY;
     }

  function afterpostback() {

            var h = document.getElementById("<%=hfScrollPosition.ClientID%>");
            document.getElementById("<%=scrollArea.ClientID%>").scrollTop = h.value;

     }

</script> 

 <asp:HiddenField ID="hfScrollPosition" runat="server" Value="0" />
 <div id="scrollArea" onscroll="SetDivPosition()"   runat="server"  style="height:225px;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;">
```

In the Page_Load

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "CallJS", "afterpostback();", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont have a long long explanation and any explanation, the most important part is these codes work on my project.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
// This Script is used to maintain Grid Scroll on Partial Postback
var scrollTop;
//Register Begin Request and End Request 
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
//Get The Div Scroll Position

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) 
{
var m = document.getElementById('divGrid');
scrollTop=m.scrollTop;
}
//Set The Div Scroll Position
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
var m = document.getElementById('divGrid');
m.scrollTop = scrollTop;
} 
</script>
```

this is from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30235/Maintain-GridView-Scroll-Position-and-Header-Insid

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want, but it will need to be done client-side with something like jQuery. The following tutorial uses jQuery to determine the value of the scrollbar within your GridView control and then restore that value every time the `$(document).ready` function is called. In this manner your scroll bar will be reset to it's position before the postback as you wish.

[Easily maintaining scroll position in GridView using jQuery](http://www.sergeyakopov.com/2010/11/easily-maintaining-scroll-position-in-gridview-using-jquery)

Comment: The link in your answer is now a dead link.  Could you expand your answer to explain what the article was suggesting?