# Maintian Scrollbar Of GridView Under <div> Asp.netnot working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, scroll

i have content page in which i am selecting value from drop down on which gridview populate i am here showing my aspx page,

```
 <div>
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlConsultant" runat="server" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="ddlConsultant_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtActivatedOn" runat="server">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <a href="javascript:show_calendar('<%=txtActivatedOn.ClientID%>','<%=txtActivatedOn.Text%>');">
                        <img border="0" src="./Images/calendar.gif" alt="calendar" /></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateActivated" runat="server" Text="Update Date" 
                        class="button" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="grdWithScroll" style="OVERFLOW: auto"  onscroll="SetDivPosition()">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvProjects" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="150px"
            Width="225px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowDeleting="gvProjects_RowDeleting" 
             DataKeyNames="ID" ViewStateMode="Inherit">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
             <HeaderTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_All" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_All_CheckedChanged"/>
             </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_selector" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_selector_CheckedChanged"  Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("Proj_Flag").ToString() == "True" ? "True": "False") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField  Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProjectID" Visible="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblProjectID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order #">
                    <ItemTemplate>
              <!--          <asp:Label ID="lblOrderNumber" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>-->
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="javascript:openPopup('DsProjectDetail.aspx?mode=1&cid=<%# Eval("ID") %>&prj=<%#Eval("Title")%>' )">
                            <%--<%#Eval("Title")%>--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label></a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle Width="400px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CompletionDate">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCompletionDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompletionDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ConsultantID" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblConsultantID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.gif" ButtonType="Image" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
       <input type="hidden" id="XPos" runat="server" />

    <input type="hidden" id="YPos" runat="server" />
        <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddProject" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="New Project" 
            onclick="btnAddProject_Click" />

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table> 

    </div>
```

Javascript i am using are,

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){
        var strCook = document.cookie;
        if(strCook.indexOf("!~")!=0){
          var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
          var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
          var strPos = strCook.substring(intS+2,intE);
          document.getElementById("grdWithScroll").scrollTop = strPos;
        }
      }
      function SetDivPosition(){
        var intY = document.getElementById("grdWithScroll").scrollTop;
        document.title = intY;
        document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.scrollBy(100, 100);

        function foo() {
            alert("ddd");
            if (grdWithScroll != null) alert(grdWithScroll.scrollTop);
        }
    </script>
```

and at the end of the page load event i am using,

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyKey", "SetDivPosition();", true);
```

i have added this line in

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" ...
```

and also added in webconfig,

```
 <system.web>
    <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" >
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

getting help from this link,

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092150/maintain-scroll-bar-position-of-a-div-within-a-gridview-after-a-postback
```

One think i wanna mention that "onscroll="SetDivPosition()" in div tag showing me warning that on scroll is not valid attribute for div tag

But after doing all this its not working for me firstly i populate gridview with dropdown  when grid populate it shows check box column too in all rows that on checked save check box value in database and post back occurs if i am at bottom of grid it scroll to the top after post back

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Comment: @ Answer it helps me out !

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1220070.aspx